# ORA-00902: invalid datatype 00902. 00000 - "invalid datatype"

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is my last table to create in the Oracle, but I am not really sure where is the mistake of this table.

```
CREATE TABLE PATIENTAPPOINTMENT(
APPOINTMENT_NUM VARCHAR (30) PRIMARY KEY,
STAFF_NUM VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
PATIENT_NUM VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
PROVIDER_NUM VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
APPOINTMENTDATE DATE NOT NULL,
APPOINTMENTTIME TIME NOT NULL,
EXAMROOMNUM VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT STAFFS_FK FOREIGN KEY(STAFF_NUM) REFERENCES STAFFS (STAFF_NUM),
CONSTRAINT PATIENT_FK FOREIGN KEY (PATIENT_NUM) REFERENCES PATIENT (PATIENT_NUM),
CONSTRAINT LOCAL_DOCTORS_FK FOREIGN KEY (PROVIDER_NUM) REFERENCES LOCALDOCTORS (PROVIDER_NUM));
```

[This is the error information given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFmkT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `TIME` datatype in Oracle (for column `appointmenttime`). `DATE` datatype contains both date and time, e.g.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
28.03.2020 20:44:59
```

It means that `appointmentdate  DATE` would do.

---

Apart from that, everything is OK:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE STAFFS (STAFF_NUM VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY);

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE PATIENT (PATIENT_NUM VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY);

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE LOCALDOCTORS (PROVIDER_NUM VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY);

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE PATIENTAPPOINTMENT(
  2  APPOINTMENT_NUM VARCHAR (30) PRIMARY KEY,
  3  STAFF_NUM VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  4  PATIENT_NUM VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  5  PROVIDER_NUM VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  6  APPOINTMENTDATE DATE NOT NULL,
  7  --APPOINTMENTTIME TIME NOT NULL,  --> wrong
  8  EXAMROOMNUM VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  9  CONSTRAINT STAFFS_FK FOREIGN KEY(STAFF_NUM) REFERENCES STAFFS (STAFF_NUM),
 10  CONSTRAINT PATIENT_FK FOREIGN KEY (PATIENT_NUM) REFERENCES PATIENT (PATIENT_NUM),
 11  CONSTRAINT LOCAL_DOCTORS_FK FOREIGN KEY (PROVIDER_NUM) REFERENCES LOCALDOCTORS (PROVIDER_NUM));

Table created.

SQL>
```

**except** for the fact that you should use `varchar2`, not `varchar`. Why? Because Oracle recommends so.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, this perfectly solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

TIME isn't a data type, use DATE.

VARCHAR is supported in Oracle, but not recommended, use VARCHAR2.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, will be noted for your advice.